# Database timing issue when testing express routes

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, bookshelf.js, superagent

I'm trying to test an express route which creates a record in the DB using [Bookshelf](http://bookshelfjs.org/).

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  Thing
    .forge({
      name: req.body.name
    })
    .save()
    .then((thing) => {
      res.status(201).json({
        thing: thing.toJSON()
      });
    })
});
```

To test this route, I'm making requests with [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent), reading the returned Thing ID from the response body, then looking up the `Thing` in the database to check that it exists.

```
describe('POST /', function() {
  it('creates things', function(done) {
    request(app)
      .post('/')
      .send({
        name: 'My Thing'
      })
      .end(function(err, res) {
        // res.body.thing exists and has an ID set.
        console.log("End occurred", res.body.thing.id);

        Thing
          .where('id', res.body.thing.id)
          .fetch()
          .then(function(thing) {
            // At this point, thing is null when I would expect to be
            console.log("Canvas fetched", thing);
          })
      });
  });
});
```

This looks to me like a database timing issue because the Thing definitely gets created (at least, it has an ID when it's returned in the response). I can't figure out how to debug it singe I'm new to NodeJS. I don't even seem to have SQL statements being logged.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What db you used? Are you sure the db has an id column?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned. It's PostgreSQL. It definitely has an ID column and the ID definitely has a value when the response arrives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, basically I was truncating my database in a `beforeEach` hook so I'd have a clean database for each test run.

```
beforeEach(function truncateDatabase() {
  db.truncate([
      'users'
    , 'canvases'
    , 'module_templates'
  ])
});
```

Of course, I forgot that DB truncation is async and the test and the truncate were running simultaneously. The truncate was occurring somewhere halfway through the test and destroying my setup data.

Everything worked once I changed my truncation hook to:

```
beforeEach(function truncateDatabase(done) {
  db.truncate([
      'users'
    , 'canvases'
    , 'module_templates'
  ]).then(done);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test this, but you can try it.

```
new Thing({'id': req.params.id})
.fetch()
.then(function (thins) {

});
```